# Javascript comparing object

Tags: javascript

**When you comparing object with another object with same property why it returns false?**

```
For Example 
var person={
  age:30

}

var person2={
  age:40

}

console.log(person==person) or console.log(person===person)
```

it show's in console **`false`** why?

Comment: Did you mean that `person == person2` returns false? `person == person` will always return true.

Answer (score 2):

Objects are reference types, which means the equality operators operate on a reference to the object in memory, not to its contents.

In your particular case, you could serialize the object to a string and then check

```
const compareSerializableObjects = (a, b) =>
  JSON.stringify(a) === JSON.stringify(b)
```

Comment: You could also check the individual property that you care about. Those are value types so person.age === person.age

Answer (score 1):

person === person will always return true as you are comparing the same reference, and if you are comparing person === person2 then it is a different refference which is false.
Did you mean person.age === person2.age ?